# (Spring Security Crypto Module) encrypted data Search

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, module, cryptography

I have Used Spring Security Crypto Module for data encryption . Now I want To Search these encrypted data from the database.But I am not getting any idea how do i search.Please Post something if you already faced that type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decrypt it first. You cannot search encrypted data unless you've deliberately chosen [homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) and you haven't. Note that homomorphic encryption isn't used too much in practice. Normally encrypted data should be indistinguishable from random.